# Drawing to the screen

Tags: iphone, ios5, cgcontext

I just want to draw point and line as per finger touch and moved in iphone screen. 
What is the best way to draw point in iphone?
Can anyboday tell me how to draw point as per finger touch and moved in iphone ?

Thanks,

Comment: http://blog.spritebandits.com/2012/04/17/iphone-drawing-on-screen-follow-a-finger/

Answer (score 0):

You can't "just draw" on the screen.   Closest approximation might be to save some coordinates from some view's touch delegate methods and call setNeedsDisplay.  When the view's drawRect is called, you can then use some Core Graphics (CG) drawing commands with those saved coordinates into the given drawing context.  The OS will shortly then composite that view context onto the display screen.

Answer (score 0):

check with this tutorial,i am sure it will definetly help you.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_freehand-drawing/

Answer (score 0):

you can draw line on Image or on `UIView` using `UIBezierPath` class.. in this class object you can store the user touch points and draw line using this points array..

for more details see the tutorial and demo from this link..

[Drawing on View and Image](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2011/05/uibezierpath-tutorial-for-iphone-sdk-40.html)